# Duplicating elements in a stack?

Tags: java, stack, queue

So I have a method to take a stack of Integers, and return the stack with all of the elements duplicated, and in the same order. My problem is with the method i currently have, Im getting an infinite loop problem on all cases except when the Stack is empty. What can i do to complete the duplication without a looping problem?

```
public void stutter(Stack<Integer> Integ)
{
    Integer first;

    for(int i = 0; i < Integ.size(); i++)
    {
         first = Integ.pop();
         Integ.push(first);
        Integ.push(first);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you push another integer, you increase the original size of your stack, pushing your "i" limit forward.

You should return a new Stack, preferably using (pre java8):

```
public Stack<Integer> stutter(Stack<Integer> from) {
    Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<>();
    for(Integer i: from) {
        stk.push(i);
        stk.push(i);
    }
    return stk;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ofc, its an inifinite loop. You increase the `Integ.size()` inside of the loop by `Integ.push()`.

Try something like that. Save the size inside a var befor starting to push new elements into it.

```
int size = Integ.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
   first = Integ.pop();
   Integ.push(first);
   Integ.push(first);
}
```

Comment: That did fix the infinite loop problem. But why doesn't it add the same value twice? Do I need to clone the element?

Comment: how do you print it out to see the values?

Answer (score 0):

Just create new stack with duplicates (and replace old if needed).